Copy/cutting/pasting files in sharepoint online
Is there a way to copy/cut/paste files in sharepoint online as efficiently/fast as in Windows file explorer? Right clicking > copy > select folder > confirming takes a lot longer than just drag/drop or select and using shortkeys.
The policy in our company moves us to sharepoint online, so syncing everything to file explorer is not an option.

You can enable view SharePoint Online files with File Explorer in Microsoft Edge by using group policy.
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-view-in-edge

Configure Microsoft Edge policy settings by following the steps at
Configure Microsoft Edge policy settings on Windows.

Make sure you've downloaded the Microsoft Edge administrative
template based on the operating system version or you may not see
the policy listed.

Once the template is downloaded, open the Group Policy Object Editor. Right-click Administrative Templates in the Computer Configuration or User Configuration node and select Add/Remove Templates and browse to the downloaded template.

When applying the policy, ensure you update the domain to your tenant domain or use sharepoint.com if you plan on visiting multiple SharePoint tenants.

Enabling the group policy may require a refresh of client group policy settings. After changing the group policy settings, refresh the settings. From a Command Prompt, enter GPUpdate.exe /force.


Example below with the Group Policy value:
[{"cookies": ["rtFa", "FedAuth"], "domain": "sharepoint.com"}]

